# Confused about async execution order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

So I have been trying to brush up on asynchronous programming and right now I am just at a loss for what is happening here. In my hypothetical situation I have an application which saves some data to the database and when it does this I want to fire a method to create a diff between the new version being saved and the existing version in the database. This is a slow operation and I don't want the user to have to wait because this could be done in the background. In the example I have linked below I would expect my output to be:

```
Starting
Processing Diff
Log Diff Initiated
Diff processed
```

But instead I am seeing:

```
Starting
Processing Diff
Diff processed
Log Diff Initiated
```

I could understand Processing Diff and Log Diff Initiated getting mixed up depending on timing of execution but I would definitely expect Log Diff Initiated should always be before Diff Processed because in main I did not say to await LogDiff so execution should have continued immediately with LogDiff executing asynchronously in a separate thread. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting");
    LogDiff();
    Console.WriteLine("Log Diff Initiated");
}

public static async Task LogDiff()
{
    var results = await GetDiff("Processing Diff");
    Console.WriteLine(results);
}

public static async Task<string> GetDiff(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return "Diff processed";
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/IdFgIU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Thread.Sleep` is blocking the process. Call `Task.Delay` instead and you will see the difference:

```
Starting
Processing Diff
Log Diff Initiated
Diff processed
```

Test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting");
    var task = LogDiff();
    Console.WriteLine("Log Diff Initiated");
    /// DO WHATEVER YOU WANT THEN WAIT TASK BELOW
    task.Wait();
}

public static async Task LogDiff()
{
    var results = await GetDiff("Processing Diff");
    Console.WriteLine(results);
}

public static async Task<string> GetDiff(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "Diff processed";
}
```

If you use .NET 4.0 and later:

```
public static Task Delay(double milliseconds)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += (obj, args) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    };
    timer.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I can't do this unfortunately because this application is .net 4.0 which supports async only through using Microsoft.Bcl.Async which doesn't appear to have a Task.Delay method.

Comment: Anyway, you will not need Task.Delay in your code right? Because this is for simulation only. However, we can build our own Delay method as shown in my answer.

Comment: Yes this is just for simulation but thank you this is working as I would expect now.